# Uniswap V2 getAmountOut arbitrage calculation

Tags: ethers.js, arbitrage, uniswapv2

I'm trying to learn more about arbitrage bots and it seems I'm stuck on profit calculation.
Lets say I have two different routers - Uniswap V2 and Sushiswap
To calculate possible arbitrage I use getAmountOut from both routers, so:

```
const amountIn = 1000000000000000000 // 1 ETH
const boughtAmount = await uniswapRouter.getAmountOut(amountIn, token1, token2)
const amountOut = await sushiswapRouter.getAmountOut(boughtAmount, token2, token1)
console.log(amountOut) // 994008999999999999
```

The problem is I always get the same amountOut, no matter what pair of tokens I input, or which dexes. But that shouldnt be possible, as the tokens can have different buy/sell fees.

Is there something im missing?

Comment: What are `token1` and `token2` in your question? Could you add those as const in your code example?